# How to change the color of an MKPolyline after rendering

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkpolyline

I have three lines which I'm drawing onto a map, all in the same way:

```
    MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
    self.routeLine = polyline;
```

and:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay {

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolyline *polyline = (MKPolyline *)overlay;
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:polyline];
        renderer.fillColor = [UIColor statusGreen];
        renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor statusGreen];
        renderer.lineWidth = 5;

        if (overlay == self.routeLine) { 
            self.routeLineRenderer = renderer;
        }

        return renderer;

    }

    return nil;
}
```

This is all working fine.

After a few seconds I want to change the color of one of the lines:

```
(void) changeLineColor:(id)object {
     NSLog(@"changing color");
     self.routeLineRenderer.fillColor = [UIColor statusAmber];
}
```

The method gets called and the renderer isn't nil, but the line doesn't change color. Feel I'm missing something fundamental, but not getting anywhere with the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `-setNeedsDisplay` and related methods in the ancestor `MKOverlayRenderer` class to mark areas as dirty and in need of redraw.

Comment: So `[self.routeLineRenderer setNeedsDisplay];`? Doesn't work for me?

Comment: Above, make sure this assignment is actually happening: `self.routeLineRenderer = renderer`. I have my suspicions that the `==` test isn't passing.